# Write .csv file(Excel type File) data to .csv file(Excel type File) in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an excel `.csv` file that has some data in the below formats in cells:

```
NAME Address Contact
Shoeb   Lko 675567
Rajesh  Banaras 7687678
```

.csv file is not a text file having only .csv extension. It is a csv file that is made using Microsoft Excel file...For testing you can also make .csv file... For this (1) create an excel file (2) open this excel file (3) go to file menu and click on "save as" (4) select CSV(Comma Seperated) option in Save as type:    ---- Now this is .csv file from which I will read content and write content also in a .csv file

I am trying to use C# to write another Excel `.csv` file in the same format.

***Code that I am using is written below:***

```
//Below line is reading file from system drive
    StreamReader rd = new StreamReader("D:\FilesUploadedToTablet\drivers.csv", true);
//Below line is writing data to file existing in our site folder
    StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath(".") + "\filename\CSVFile.csv");
    wr.Write(rd.ReadToEnd());
    rd.Close();
    wr.Close();
```

Here `StreamReader` is reading `drivers.csv` file but `StreamWriter` is not writing that content to the `CSVFile.csv` file. If I use any text file in place of .csv file then the content writes successfully. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think the issue isn't related to CSV specifically. Something like writing permissions or file locks may be the subject. What is the output of `Server.MapPath(".")`?

Comment: "but something wrong" is not at all helpful. _What_ specifically went wrong? What was the error message that you got?

Comment: Actually StreamWriter writes content provided by StreamReader in .txt file(destination file in which i will write) very well but I want to use .csv file as destination file (destination file in which i will write) then It doesn't works and also it doesn't produce any error. Given Code is ok if i am using .txt file as a destination file in which i have to write in place of .csv file. File path are also correct.

Comment: .csv file is not a text file having only .csv extension. It is a csv file that is made using Microsoft Excel file...For testing you can also make .csv file... For this (1) create an excel file (2) open this excel file (3) go to file menu and click on "save as" (4) select CSV(Comma Seperated) option in Save as type:    ---- Now this is .csv file from which I will read content and write content also in a .csv file

Comment: Here is nothing wrong with Server.MapPath(".") It's ok

Comment: FYI: CSV __is__ a text file format. If it is not a text file, then it is not a CSV file. It is completely irrelevant what it was created with.

Comment: when StreamReader reads data from .csv file then it automatically appends comma (,) after each cell content of a row and appends \r\n after each row. but StreamWriter is unable tu understand that comma tells next cell and \r\n tells new row in .csv file. So it doesn't writes in .csv file it only writes in .txt file

Comment: I don't think you understand what CSV is. Please read following wiki page very carefully http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

Comment: when StreamReader reads data from .csv file then it automatically appends comma (,) after each cell content of a row and appends \r\n after each row.                                                above given data in question is returned by StreamReader as "NAME,Address,Contact\r\nShoeb,Lko,675567r\nRajesh,Banaras,7687678" StreamWriter is unable tu understand that comma tells next cell and \r\n tells new row in .csv file. So it doesn't writes in .csv file it only writes in .txt file

Comment: .csv file is not a text file having only .csv extension and its content separated by comma. It is a csv file that is made using Microsoft Excel file.that cells contains data. For testing you can also make .csv file... For this (1) create an excel file (2) open this excel file (3) go to file menu and click on "save as" (4) select CSV(Comma Seperated) option in Save as type: ---- Now this is .csv file from which I will read content and write content also in a .csv file

Comment: @Shoeb You are completely mistaken. StreamReader does _not_ automatically append a comma after each cell. StreamReader does not know anything about "cells" or "rows". StreamWriter does not know anything about the commas because that is not its job. The commas are in your data because it's a CSV file. If the data was not separated by commas then it would not be a CSV file. I still cannot figure out what it is that you think is a problem. One thing is your file paths. The first path would translate to "D:\ilesUploadedToTablet\rivers.csv" because you did not escape the "\".

Comment: Dear PhoenixReborn, I know that csv file contains comma separated values like Mango,Apple,23,England. But this csv file is of Excel sheet. I am not wrong when you open a excel file and go to save as of File menu then you will get an option to convert this .xls file to .csv file by selecting CSV(Comma Seperated) option in Save as type: then you will see that this csv file has extension .csv but it's display is same as excel file when you open this file.

Comment: so if this file contains values in their cells and you will read this file using StreamReader then you will get the content of this file in a comma separated string automatically. But I am unable to write this kind of comma separated content back to the same formatted .csv file. Please help...

Comment: Thanx all of you for suggesting me...I got it's solution

Comment: Solution that I got is written below :                           string csvContent = string.Empty;
if (File.Exists(FilePath))
{ StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(SourceFilePath, true);
  csvContent = rd.ReadToEnd();
  rd.Close(); var DestPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/CSV Files/") + "MyFile.csv";
        StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(DestPath, true);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(csvContent);
        wr.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        sb.Clear();
        wr.Close();

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a BinaryReader() instead of the StreamReader(). Also try opening the StreamReader as follows:

```
   StreamReader("D:\FilesUploadedToTablet\drivers.csv", false);
```

It looks like you are only copying the file, not filtering or performing any processing on it. Why not just use File.Copy:

```
  File.Copy("D:\FilesUploadedToTablet\drivers.csv", Server.MapPath(".") + "\filename\CSVFile.csv");
```

Comment: .csv file is not a text file having only .csv extension and its content separated by comma. It is a csv file that is made using Microsoft Excel file.that cells contains data. For testing you can also make .csv file... For this (1) create an excel file (2) open this excel file (3) go to file menu and click on "save as" (4) select CSV(Comma Seperated) option in Save as type: ---- Now this is .csv file from which I will read content and write content also in a .csv file.

Comment: When StreamReader reads data from .csv file then it automatically appends comma (,) after each cell content of a row and appends \r\n after each row. above given data in question is returned by StreamReader as "NAME,Address,Contact\r\nShoeb,Lko,675567r\nRajesh,Banaras,7687678" StreamWriter is unable tu understand that comma tells next cell and \r\n tells new row in .csv file. So it doesn't writes in .csv file it only writes in .txt file

Comment: Can you cut-copy-paste the first few lines from "D:\FilesUploadedToTablet\drivers.csv" here?

Comment: 28 Robert London s-02 80 James Banaras s-01 17 Milton America s-01 62 Raju Japan s-01 72 Kapoor Bihar G-2006-01

Comment: There are no comma's in this file; StreamReader cannot add comma's by itself.

Comment: Dear Grynn, I know that csv file contains comma separated values like Mango,Apple,23,England. But this csv file is of Excel sheet. I am not wrong when you open a excel file and go to save as of File menu then you will get an option to convert this .xls file to .csv file by selecting CSV(Comma Seperated) option in Save as type: then you will see that this csv file has extension .csv but it's display is same as excel file when you open this file.

Comment: so if this file contains values in their cells and you will read this file using StreamReader then you will get the content of this file in a comma separated string automatically. But I am unable to write this kind of comma separated content back to the same formatted .csv file. Please help...

Comment: Here when you read data using streamReader from .csv file then it becomes automatically as ... 28, Robert London, s-02\r\n 80, James Banaras, s-01\r\n 17, Milton America, s-01\r\n 62, Raju Japan, s-01\r\n 72, Kapoor Bihar, G-2006-01  file in a comma separated string automatically. But I am unable to write this kind of comma separated content back to the same formatted .csv file. Please help...

Comment: Thanx all of you for suggesting me...I got it's solution –  Solution that I got is written below : string csvContent = string.Empty; if (File.Exists(FilePath)) { StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(SourceFilePath, true); csvContent = rd.ReadToEnd(); rd.Close(); var DestPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/CSV Files/") + "MyFile.csv"; StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(DestPath, true); StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(csvContent); wr.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); sb.Clear(); wr.Close();

Answer (score 0):

Thanx all of you for suggesting me...
I got it's solution – Solution that I got is written below :

```
string csvContent = string.Empty; 
if (File.Exists("SourceFilePath")) 
{ 
    StreamReader rd = new StreamReader("SourceFilePath", true); 
    csvContent = rd.ReadToEnd(); 
    rd.Close(); 
    var DestPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/CSV Files/")+"MyFile.csv";     
    StreamWriter wr = new StreamWriter(DestPath, true); 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(csvContent); 
    wr.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); 
    sb.Clear(); 
    wr.Close();
```